# How can I find the data parameters required for a requests.post function with a specific URL?

Tags: python, python-requests, aiohttp

I would like to use the requests library to make a request to a particular webpage, http://latex2png.com/api/convert, in order to convert some latex to a PNG image. However, I am unsure of what data parameters the website accepts.

Is there any way to use the `requests` library to see which parameters need to be fulfilled?

I've tried running

```py
options = {
    "auth": {"user": "guest", "password": "guest"},
    "latex": '$a^3$',
    "resolution": 900,
    "color": "969696",
}

r = requests.post('http://latex2png.com/api/convert')

print(r.content)
```

but I get `b'{"result-message":"no request","result-code":-2}'`.

There is no documentation or help online with this specific API and website.

Comment: Hey you can use Chrome's Network Tab or a software called Fiddler to intercept raw requests and then replicate with python

Comment: You can accomplish the conversion using imagemagick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the way you post is wrong, try this:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
}

data = {
    "auth": {
        "user": "guest",
        "password": "guest"
    },
    "latex": "a^3",
    "resolution": 600,
    "color": "969696"
}

r = requests.post('http://latex2png.com/api/convert', headers=headers, json=data) # the right way to send POST requests
print(r.json())  # print the json
image_url = "http://latex2png.com" + r.json()['url']
r = requests.get(image_url)
with open("download.png", "wb+") as f: # download it.
    f.write(r.content)
```